# Lenovo S10-2 - Internet connection LED

Tags: windows-xp, internet-connection, lenovo-laptop

I'm using a [Lenovo S10-2](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/laptops/ideapad/s-series/s10-2) with Windows XP home. Recently the LED on the front that indicates the internet connection starts blinking from time to time. Usually it's either on or off.
Why is it blinking and is there a way to turn it off? (It's a bit distracting)

Thsi is the LED:

[image]

Comment: Is it a wireless connection? Are you sure the connection's stable?

Comment: Yes, it's a wireless connection and it's stable. Is there a way to switch the LED completly off? (I don't need the indicator)

Comment: Not sure, will have to look into it. If there isn't, a low-tech solution would be to simply use some masking tape.